# Program not recognizing the variable as long int nor as unsigned int

Tags: c, integer, overflow, long-integer, unsigned-integer

Instead of getting number "2147483648" I get "-2147483648" because of an signed int overflow. I tried declaring the variable both as long int as well as unsigned int with no use. They are just not recognized as such types. If anyone wondering, I'm left shiffting the value.

```
int multiplier = 1,i;
long int mpy = 0;
for(i=32;i>=0;i--){
mpy = 1 << multiplier++;
printf("mpy = %d\n",mpy);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete, minimal and verifiable example.

Comment: I did Daniel, although you just needed to loop it until it overflows as a signed int

Comment: Overflow of signed types leads to undefined behaviour.  You don't know what will happen.  You can experiment and find out what usually happens, but there's no guarantee that what usually happens is what will always happen, nor that other compilers, or other versions of the compiler, will do things the same way.

Comment: Using `%d` in your `printf()` format string will print an unsigned int as though it were a signed int with the same bits set... and similarly, using `%u` will display either signed or unsigned ints as unsigned.

Comment: Thanks for the tip tho, I'm not much of a C guy, I came from an OOP environment so those printf tags are novelty for me, first time I meet with %u, by now I had experience only with a few of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the constant `1` is an `int`, when shifted left, it remains an `int`.  If you want an `unsigned long long`, make it such:

```
unsigned long long mpy = 1ULL << multiplier++;
```

You could use one of the suffixes `L` or `UL` or `LL` for `long`, `unsigned long` and `long long` instead (and lower-case versions of these, but the suffix is best written in upper-case to avoid confusion of `l` and `1`).  The choice depends on what you're really trying to do.

Note that the type of the result of `<<` is the type of the left-hand operand.  The result of the shift is only subsequently converted to the type of the left-hand side of the assignment operator.  The LHS of the assignment does not affect how the value on the RHS is calculated.

As [user3528438](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3528438/user3528438) pointed out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999056/program-not-recognizing-the-variable-as-long-int-nor-as-unsigned-int/31999158#comment51901803_31999158), and as I assumed (perhaps mistakenly) you would know — if `multiplier` (the RHS of the `<<` operator) evaluates to a negative value or a value equal to or larger than the number of bits in the integer type, then you invoke undefined behaviour.

Note that `long long` and `unsigned long long` are standard in the decade-and-a-half old standard (C99) and the newer C11 standard — but they were not part of the quarter-century old C89/C90 standard.  If you're stuck on a platform where the compiler is in a time-warp — release date in the 201x decade and C standard compatibility date of 1990 — then you have to go with alternative platform-specific 64-bit techniques.  The loop in the updated question covers 33 values since you count from 32 down to and including 0.  No 32-bit type will have distinct values for each of the 33 shifts.

(Advanced users might be interested in [INT35-C Use correct integer precisions](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/INT35-C.+Use+correct+integer+precisions) and [N1899 — Integer precision bits update](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1899.pdf); they're a tad esoteric for most people as yet.  I'm not sure whether I'll ever find it necessary to worry about the issue raised.)

Note also the discussion in the comments below about [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) formats.  You should make sure you print the value with the correct format.  For `long int`, that should be `%ld`; for `unsigned long long`, that would be `%llu`.  Other types require other formats.  Make sure you're using sensible compiler warning options.  If you're using GCC, you should look at `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c11` as a rather effective set of options; I use slightly more stringent options than even those when I'm compiling C code.

Comment: Also important to note that `1<<32` is UB for most implementations where `1` is `int` and `int` is less than or equal to 32bits.

Comment: Although it seemed very reasonable solution, unfortunately it was of no use to me :(

Comment: @Maxitj: Bad luck.  I imagine that means you're stuck with Microsoft compilers.  It's worth saying so because people assume that you're using a more or less modern compiler supporting a more or less modern standard unless you indicate otherwise.

Comment: Perhaps this will shed some light onto the issue: http://ideone.com/sMUFZv If you want and find it helpful, it can be included into the answer.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Sorry I didn't point earlier, but I'm using GCC compiler

Comment: @Maxitj: OK.  Which version of GCC, and on which platform?  (If Windows, under Cygwin or with MinGW?)  Why was the answer no use to you?  It's hard to help much if you don't explain what went wrong.  I made one plausible but erroneous hypothesis.  I'm cautious about guessing that you've got too old a version of GCC; it has to be very old.  Does the platform support 64-bit arithmetic at all?  If not, trying to fit 33 bits into a 32-bit pot isn't going to work well.  Remember, we only know what you tell us about your problem.  We can sometimes guess what's going wrong — but not infallibly.

Comment: Also we ignored the fact( as @Dmitri haspointed out) that OP is using `%d`. What s/he was really asking is why `unsignd int mpy = 1U<<31;` overflows, and answer is to chagne `%d` to `%u`.

Comment: @DanielJour Daniel the thing is, I'm restricted to one library (<stdio.h>), and anyway the computer on which I am supposed to compile the code is 32bit based.

Comment: @user3528438: well, yes — the `%d` format is only for `int`, not `long int` as it is shown (and not for `unsigned int` or `unsigned long`, strictly).  You get away with blue murder (mismatched format specifiers) when `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)`, doubly so when printing a single-value and with little-endian platforms (Intel).  Since `mpy` was marked as `long int`, it is not clear that the question was looking at `unsigned int`.  But the formatting of the printed data is also an issue.

Comment: @Maxitj That's all part of one library ... the *C standard library*. If you're restricted to one *header*, then you should go and get a reference of the C standard library and throw it into the face of the one imposing that restriction.

Comment: I suspected on those printf tags but obviously not enough, yeah that helped certainly. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what compiler you are using, and if you are compiling in 32-bit vs. 64-bit mode, what you are seeing could be exactly as expected.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/size-of-long-integer-type-on-different-architecture-and-os

tl;dr: with MSVC, both `int` and `long` are 32-bits, you need to graduate up to `__int64` if you want to store a bigger number. With gcc or other compilers in 32-bit mode, you run into the same issue of `int` = `long` = 32-bit, which doesn't help you in your situation. Only when you make the move to 64-bit compilation on non-Microsoft compilers do `int` and `long` start to diverge.

edit per comments section:
`int64_t` or `long long` would also be standards-compliant types that could be used. Alternatively, `unsigned` would allow the poster to fit their value into 32-bits.

Comment: Note that `__int64` is specific to Microsoft compilers (and compilers providing compatibility with MS code).  It is not standardized in any other way.

Comment: With all due respect, you're wrong. Unsigned integer is supposed to be  32bit from 0 to      4294967295. I am still working inside the borders of 32bit. And one more thing yeah, as the guy above mentioned, what would happen with long long then :)

Comment: Maxitj, the original poster does not have "unsigned" in his/her code. You're right, if the original code can be modified to be unsigned, then 32-bits is plenty, but as written, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Maxitj because your `%d` in `printf` printed it wrong. Use `%u` to correctly print `unsigned int`. And change `1<<multiplier++;` to `1u<<multiplier++` to avoid overflow UB.